# Scholarly papers on Cryptocurrencies/Electronic Money

Tags: reference-request, monetary-policy, cryptocurrency

Does anyone know of any peer-reviewed papers on the topic of [Cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency) or Electronic Money and its acceptance and practice in the financial market?

Thanks!